# How to make a color grid in python using pil?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am a complete rookie and I want to make a 10*10 color grid with random colors. I have progressed to making a row with my code but I can't progress ahead.

```
import random
import uuid

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

run_id = uuid.uuid1()

print(f'Processing run_id: {run_id}')

image = Image.new('RGB', (1600, 1600))
width, height = image.size

rectangle_width = 160
rectangle_height = 160

draw_image = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
for i in range(10):
    rectangle_x = i*160
    rectangle_y = 0

    rectangle_shape = [
        (rectangle_x, rectangle_y),
        (rectangle_x + rectangle_width, rectangle_y + rectangle_height)]
    draw_image.rectangle(
        rectangle_shape,
        fill=(
            random.randint(0, 255),
            random.randint(0, 255),
            random.randint(0, 255)
        )
    )

image.save(f'./output/{run_id}.png')
```

This is what I am trying to achieve but with random colors

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code, it appears that you only have a loop for 1 single row (the row on top of your square). By adding another for loop (looping over each row in your square; denoted by `j`) you can draw a colored square for each row.

When showing the output, I got your [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncwlw.jpg)

```py
import random
import uuid

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

run_id = uuid.uuid1()

print(f'Processing run_id: {run_id}')

image = Image.new('RGB', (1600, 1600))
width, height = image.size

rectangle_width = 160
rectangle_height = 160

draw_image = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        rectangle_x = i*160
        rectangle_y = j*160
    
        rectangle_shape = [
            (rectangle_x, rectangle_y),
            (rectangle_x + rectangle_width, rectangle_y + rectangle_height)]
        draw_image.rectangle(
            rectangle_shape,
            fill=(
                random.randint(0, 255),
                random.randint(0, 255),
                random.randint(0, 255)
            )
        )

image.save(f'./output/{run_id}.png')

image.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is considerably easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Generate 10x10 grid of random colours
grid = np.random.randint(0,256, (10,10,3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Make into PIL Image and scale up using Nearest Neighbour
im = Image.fromarray(grid).resize((1600,1600), resample=Image.NEAREST)

im.save('result.png')
```

[image]